# How do I add an icon instead of ">>" in CakePHP pagination?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, pagination

How do I add an icon instead of `">>"` in CakePHP pagination?

The code:

```
 echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ', array('limit' => '10'));
```

Views:

```
<span class="prev">
<a href="#" rel="prev"> << </a>
</span>
```

I want it to be:

```
 <span class="prev"><a href="#"  rel="prev">
 <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> </a>
 </span>
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resolved

it should use 
`'escape' => false` to run it as html code

example

`echo $this->Paginator->prev('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', array('limit' => '6','escape' => false,));`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), download it and paste files brings the package, then just add the following line in your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-route/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

then just add the icon to your php like this:

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev('<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>', array('limit' => '10'));
```

you can check the diferents icons [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

i hope it helps you...

Comment: thanks.
the issue that it prints the code as it is not html !
   <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>